# How do i write/Load my Dataset To/From XML

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, vba

I currently have a table ready to take input from a form in my Stocklist App system.

I would like to be able to save the data from the table into an XML file ready to load again the next time the user opens the program.

The current code i am using is this...

```
Dim entryno As Integer = 1
IDColumn.Table.WriteXml("C:\Users\User\Documents\Stocklist\XML\" & entryno & ".xml")
entryno += 1
```

But nothing is being created?

My Dataset is called "StockdataDataSet.xsd"

my datable is called "DataTable1"

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is DataSet.WriteXml and DataTable.WriteXml for saving to xml then the reverse DataSet.ReadXml etc. xsd would be an extension for a xml schema file. I would suggest making sure the DataSet has data via using a break-point then examining the tables within and change the extension for the file to .xml

Comment: The DataTable WriteXml() method only works if the DataTable has a name property.  The DataSet method work with/without a name.  So you can either add a name to the table or use the DataSet method.  I also recommend using the WriteSchema option so the columns have the same type every time you write/read the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example using hard-coded data so you can see what I was talking about. Place a break point where noted in the Console.WriteLine then examine the DataSet.

```
Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyData.xml")

Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable With {.TableName = "Person"}
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "FirstName", .DataType = GetType(String)})
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "MiddleName", .DataType = GetType(String)})
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "LastName", .DataType = GetType(String)})

dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Karen", "Ann", "Payne"})
dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Kevin", "S", "Gallagher"})
dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Mary", "D", "Jones"})

ds.Tables.Add(dt)

ds.WriteXml(fileName)
Console.WriteLine("place a break point here")
ds.Clear()
ds.ReadXml(fileName)
Console.WriteLine("place a break point here")
```

Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Karen</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Ann</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Payne</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Kevin</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>S</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Gallagher</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>D</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Jones</LastName>
  </Person>
</NewDataSet>
```

Note the DataSet name of NewDataSet, let's change that by creating the data set as follows

```
Dim ds As New DataSet With {.DataSetName = "People"}
```

Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<People>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Karen</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Ann</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Payne</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Kevin</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>S</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Gallagher</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>D</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Jones</LastName>
  </Person>
</People>
```

Comment: Interesting sample data ;)

Comment: This all goes in the Form load? i presume, well except from the Write XML bits?, they should go in the save function?

Comment: In regards to doing the read in form load, sure. You might consider creating a class and placing the read and write operations there and then call from Form Load and on save a button click or even on Form Closing event but best to write the bulk of the code in a class then setup an instance of the class as private in the form, call methods in this class to do your work.

Comment: Karen you're terrific!

Comment: Hi Jamie, if the solution I provided worked for you consider marking it as answered so that others who are looking for this know it resolved the question but don't mark it if it did not resolve the question.

Comment: Im still working on it, i'm pretty new to VB.net and still a student, so i'm struggling through to see what goes where

Comment: Jamie, I created a sample in VS2013 which will work in VS2015 too. There are two projects, a class project for working the xml while a forms project demos reading and writing. There is a ton of assertion so being new to this it might take a bit to learn. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!909&authkey=!AKb-1koZa6XzUdw&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: I really just need the write/load bits, so do i really need to use the add column lines?

Comment: You don't need the add column lines, they are there purely to demonstrate what comes after that, without the mocked data you would not be able to try the sample out and get the expected results.